# Table primeNg 5.2.7 - Nested Object

Tags: primeng

I paint a table with primeNg that has an object that in turn contains other objects.

// controller

```
this.cols = [
        { field: 'persona', subfield: 'dni', header: 'NIF' },
        { field: 'persona', subfield: 'nombre', header: 'Nombre' },
        { field: 'persona', subfield: 'apellido1', header: 'Apellido 1' },
        { field: 'persona', subfield: 'apellido2', header: 'Apellido 2' },
        { field: 'emailEmpresa', header: 'Email' }
    ];
```

// view

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <div *ngIf="col.subfield;then nested_object_content else normal_content"></div>
                <ng-template #nested_object_content>
                    {{rowData[col.field][col.subfield]}}
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #normal_content>
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </ng-template>
            </td>
        </tr>
   </ngTemplate>
```

// The problem is when exporting it to a csv:

```
dataTable.exportCSV();
```

// When creating the CSV instead of putting the value of the nested values, I get the following:

```
[object Object]
```

How can I get the value out correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below :

```
this.cols = [
        {field: 'persona.dni', header: 'NIF'},
        {field: 'persona.nombre', header: 'Nombre'},
        {field: 'persona.apellido1', header: 'Apellido 1'},
        {field: 'persona.apellido2', header: 'Apellido 2'},
        {field: 'emailEmpresa', header: 'Email'}
    ];

<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-value>
    <tr>
        <td>{{value.persona.dni}}</td>
        <td>{{value.persona.nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{value.persona.apellido1}}</td>
        <td>{{value.persona.apellido2}}</td>
        <td>{{value.emailEmpresa}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

It will resolve the `exportCSV()` function's nested `[object Object]` scenario in final CSV file.